# Many-To-Many Relation by storing comma-separated ids in a column?

Tags: postgresql, many-to-many

Is it OK to sometimes instead of making a join table for a many-to-many relation, store the ids of entity A in a column of entity B? It would look something like this:

```
// A
id | name
---------
10 | foo
20 | bar

// B
id | name | AIds
-----------------
30 | buzz | 10,20
```

I only need to know which A's are owned by B when looking at B, and not the other way around (and I can handle the logic in code, joins are not necessary). Hence the lack of a join table.

Or are there some bad aspects to this I'm not seeing?

Comment: **DO**. **NOT**. **DO**. THAT.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name does that not help me at all

Comment: @mustaccio I decided to **DO**. **DO**. THAT. My code fetches a `A` record in advance anyway and only needs to know if it is owned by a given `B` which is as simple as selecting `B` by its ids and checking if `A.id` is in `B.AIds` in code. That's all the logic I need.

Comment: Why do you ask, if you are not willing to listen to good advice? Your proposed implementation is inefficient. The proper and efficient way to do this is by joining the tables.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've read the linked post and made a decision??? My implementation is nothing but efficient, you clearly did not understand my use case. I asked if there were some bad aspects I was not seeing, and it turns out that in most cases this is bad, but in my case it's actually beneficial.
And the "DO. NOT. DO. THAT." comment is far from being advice.